# Protect your option value

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am creating a drop down menu by accessing my database, fetch the data, and then display them using a for loop. At the end the result is something like this:

```
 <select>
   <option value="1">USA</option>
   <option value="2">Spain</option>
   <option value="3">Greece</option>
   <option value="4">China</option>
 </select>
```

**Purpose:** Customize your profile by selecting country/state/city/language. This will be visible on the user's profile at all times.

As soon as the user selects an option (let's say USA), the value of USA (1) is used to return the states of USA.

By inspecting the element, I can easily change the value of USA from 1 to 200, and submit the form. This will disturb the back end system calculations and cause problems to the client.[the states/cities are linked to country selection]

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

I am thinking of testing if the value selected is available inside the database and only accept it if its in.

Comment: backend validation you mentioned should take care of this. by inspecting the form one can even add non-existent fields or remove the ones you need.

Comment: simply you can store value in php variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your note in *PS* has the right idea.  There is no way to prevent people from tampering with the data in their browser.  One has to act accordingly, every piece of data coming back from the client is untrusted and should be validated where possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for whitelist validation in the php server code.

```
if( ! is_int($value) || $value > 4){
   // Validation failed here   
}
```